# How to use generator function in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, generator

I am trying to use generator function in typescript. But the compiler throws error

`error TS2339: Property 'next' does not exist on type`

Below is an closest sample of my code.

```
export default class GeneratorClass {
    constructor() {
        this.generator(10);
        this.generator.next();
    }
    *generator(count:number): Iterable<number | undefined> {
        while(true)
            yield count++;
    }   
}
```

[Here is the playground link for the same](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20default%20class%20GeneratorClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.generator(10)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.generator.next()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20*generator(count%3Anumber)%3A%20Iterable%3Cnumber%20%7C%20undefined%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20while(true)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20yield%20count%2B%2B%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The `next` method exists on the generator that the function returns, not on the generator function itself.

```
export default class GeneratorClass {
    constructor() {
        const iterator = this.generator(10);
        iterator.next();
    }
    *generator(count:number): IterableIterator<number> {
        while(true)
            yield count++;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Did you try this in the playground, it has the same result error TS2339: Property 'next' does not exist on type

Comment: @anandaravindan: Change the type from `Iterable` to `Iterator`.

Comment: @FelixKling Thankyou. Just now checked the documentation, the return type is IterableIterator.

Comment: @anandaravindan Nah, I didn't. Appears that you need to change the type to the more specific `Iterator`, or call `this.generator(10)[Symbol.iterator]()`

Comment: @Bergi, can you edit the answer to return IterableIterator which I verified in the typescript docs, so the answer can be helpfull for others

Comment: @anandaravindan I'm curious, what's the difference between `Iterator` and `IterableIterator`?

Comment: @anandaravindan Thanks for sharing this. A link to the docs would be helpful.

Comment: Where is this in the typescript documentation?

Comment: @SystemParadox No idea, it's in the javascript documentation.

Comment: @Bergi an `Iterator` has a `next` method. An `Iterable` has a `Symbol.iterator` property returning an iterator. An object which has both (`next` method and `Symbol.iterator` property) is called an `IterableIterator`. You can read more about it here: https://typescript.tv/hands-on/understanding-generators-iterators-and-iterables/ There is also a video tutorial about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZN0Lo-f3iE

Answer (score 9):

To solve the problem, it is very important to know the differences between generator functions (generators for short) and their return values.

A **generator function** (marked by the asterisk) is a function, which returns a generator object. The generator object fulfills the requirements of an **iterator** and an **iterable**.

**Iterators** have a `next` method (that's the method you are looking for in your question). And **iterables** have a property called `Symbol.iterator` (specifying a default iterator), which makes them usable in for-loops.

Because a generator function returns a generator object and a generator object is an iterable iterator, you have to declare a return type of `IterableIterator`. In your case it will be `IterableIterator<number>`.

Because the terms here are confusingly similar, I have recorded a [Generator tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZN0Lo-f3iE) which explains the differences. Make sure to set your `target` to `es6` in your `tsconfig.json`, when using generator functions.

Answer (score 8):

I was seeing this error because my **tsconfig.json** was targeting `es5`.

I simply changed (excerpted) from:

```json
"target": "es5",
"lib": [
    "es5",
    "es2015.promise"
]
```

to:

```json
"target": "es6",
"lib": [
    "es6"
]
```

and the error went away.

Note: For VS Code I needed to reload the window for IntelliSense to recognize the change.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another example which uses the Generator type of typescript. Some of the types at the assignment of iterators e.g. `const iterator: Generator<number>` can be omitted since TS can infer them. However I included them in this example to be more explicit.

```
class GeneratorClass {
    *generator(count:number): Generator<number> {
        while(count < 3)
            yield count++;
    }   
}

const generatorObject = new GeneratorClass();

// Getting our generator object which we can use as an iterator.
const iterator: Generator<number> = generatorObject.generator(1);


console.log(iterator.next());
console.log(iterator.next());
console.log(iterator.next());
/*
[LOG]: {
  "value": 1,
  "done": false
} 
[LOG]: {
  "value": 2,
  "done": false
} 
[LOG]: {
  "value": undefined,
  "done": true
} 
*/

// Alternative more clean for of syntax. 
// For of can iterate over any iterable
// Can be used since every Generator is an Iterator
const iterator2: Generator<number> = generatorObject.generator(1);
```